# RegEnumKeyEx doesn't change file name Qt

Tags: winapi, registry

I'm a very new to winapi and having a lot of troubles

Trying to extract all connected COM ports and write them to the prompt line.

```
HKEY hKey;
if (RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,TEXT("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM"),&hKey)==ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
DWORD NumKeys;
DWORD i;
TCHAR KeyNameBuf[255];
DWORD keyNameSizBuf=255;
RegQueryInfoKey(hKey,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,&NumKeys,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
for (i=0;i<NumKeys-1;i++)
{
    keyNameSizBuf=15;
    RegEnumKeyEx(hKey,i,KeyNameBuf,&keyNameSizBuf,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    qDebug() <<KeyNameBuf;
}
}
```

The problem: it doesn't change the KeyNameBuf and keeps it null.

Any ideas?
Thank you, and sorry in advance if it is something trivial...

Comment: You should check the return value of the Reg* API calls.  It's likely the RegEnumKeyEx call is failing, and returning a non-zero error code that would indicate what's going on.

Comment: Also, why are you setting keyNameSizBuf to 15?

Comment: Just arbitrary, because I've read somewhere it should be initialized at each time.

Comment: Read the doc on msdn.microsoft.com.  The value is important, it shouldn't be initialized to something arbitrary.  It probably explains the failure.

Comment: It wasn't completely arbitrary, the msdn suggested to input the longest value from RegQueryInfoKey, which was 15 so I've just set it to that number.

Comment: You should set it to the number of characters in the buffer you're providing.  MSDN suggested that you size your buffer based on the "max size" reported by RegQueryInfoKey, but I don't see your code querying that -- you're just querying the count of keys.

Comment: The loop `for (i=0;i<NumKeys-1;i++)` looks suspicious. Is skipping the last key intended? Shouldn't the condition be `i<NumKeys` or `i<=NumKeys-1` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found:
RegEnumKeyEx retrieve the data pointers (optional argument 7), and then convert int from Byte* to const char *